# .net core (.net framework) mvc System.MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, akka.net

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Autofac": "4.6.0",
    "Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "4.1.0",
    "AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection": "2.0.1",
    "xx.Service.Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "Akka": "1.2.0",
    "Akka.Remote": "1.2.0",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.3.2",
    "DotNetty.Transport": "0.4.5",
    "DotNetty.Handlers": "0.4.5",
    "DotNetty.Codecs": "0.4.5",
    "DotNetty.Buffers": "0.4.5",
    "DotNetty.Common": "0.4.5",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "10.0.2",
    "System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource": "4.3.1",
    "AutoMapper": "6.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "1.1.3",
    "xx.Web.Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "2.0.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "2.0.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions": "2.0.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "2.0.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "1.1.2"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net462": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Anadolum.Shared.Messages": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "copyToOutput": {
      "include": [ "appsettings.json", "rawrabbit.json" ]
    }
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config",
      "rawrabbit.json"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
  //,
  //"runtimes": {
  //  "win7-x64": {}
  //}
}
```

This is the startup code

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
host.Run();
```

I can't fix this error below. This is my package.config file.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException'
>   occurred in xxx.exe.
>
> Additional information: Method not found: 'System.IServiceProvider
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)'.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You seem to have a package which is not compatible with your current setup, and due to that, the invocation of the missing method fails, however you give very little information, like when does this error happen?

Comment: var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();

Comment: Yes,I think like you but I don't know how to fix it. I follow the error message and fix the version on DLL not found errors. How can I check which version is right ?

Comment: I wonder if this question is still actual. I had this problem and solved it, but don't remember how. Suppose it was connected with Autofac and AspnetCore integration. Did you follow the instructions from Autofac? http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html